# Multimodule gradle build jar

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I have a multi-module gradle build in intellij , where the parent ( java standalone httpclient ) project includes a utils project using :-

`implementation project (project-name)` inside `dependencies{`

When i run a gradle build, the jar that gets created in the build folder does not contain the classes / jar of the util project when i do a `jar tvf <jarname>.jar`

However, it is visible as a sub project in the gradle tool window -> task -> source sets in intellij.

One way i could get the subproject included in the parent jar was to publish it on nexus, include the snapshot and create a "jar" task. But since that deviates from the multi-module structure, it is not an acceptable solution.

Any pointers on getting the jar imported please?

PS :- The parent project is not a spring application so i cannot use the spring dependency management plugin.

Comment: Each sub-project in a Gradle multi-project build creates a separate artifact. If you want to create a fat/uber JAR file, use a plugin such as https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle will build by default a JAR that contains only the sources of the project itself. The project also provides metadata to know which dependencies it requires. This metadata can then be used when publishing to a Maven or Ivy repository to populate the relevant metadata file.
That means consumers can then leverage that information to pull a dependency and its transitive dependencies.

What you are trying to achieve is different, since you want the dependencies to be embedded inside the JAR.
You have different options for this:

- Do it according to [the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example), if you have simple needs
- Use a [third party plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow)

What you exactly put in the JAR will depend on your specific use case.